# ¿Cómo programar una lista o un combo box en Excel que se actualice automáticamente?

Tags: excel

He encontrado dificultades para filtrar celdas que se repiten a lo largo de una columna dentro de una tabla de seguimiento de proyectos (columna de jefes de proyecto). Como ven un jefe puede tener asignado varios proyectos por lo que algunos se repiten a lo largo de la columna. Estoy haciendo en otra hoja un informe y necesito de alguna manera una lista de los jefes en la cual no se repitan los datos para poder realizar cálculos posteriores, pero el tema es que deseo que esta lista se actualice de forma automática puesto que a la tabla se le irá agregando y aumentando filas (nuevos jefes o menos jefes). Cualquier idea para abordar el tema será de mucha ayuda.

Comment: "Cualquier idea para abordar el tema" hace que la pregunta sea basada en opiniones. Es mejor ser más específico además de indicar que es lo que se ha buscado/investigado sobre tema.

Comment: Se pueden mostrar las dificutades en código?

Answer (score 2):

#### Crear una tabla dinámica

3 simples pasos:

1. Seleccionar todos los datos de origen

   [image: tabla común con encabezado y datos]
2. Insertar ↣ Tabla dinámica

   [image: Insertar -> Tabla dinámica]
3. Seleccionar la columna deseada en la lista de campos de la tabla dinámica

   [image: Seleccionar Jefe de Proyecto]

#### Resultado

[image: tabla dinámica con valores únicos]

#### Actualización

[image: botón actualizar]